# Python Eve serving static files from a given folder

Tags: python, flask, eve

I build a simple REST api with Eve and Python.

```
from flask import redirect, send_from_directory, render_template
from eve import Eve
import os


PWD = os.environ.get('PWD')
public = os.path.join(PWD, 'public')


app = Eve(static_folder=public)

# serve index.html
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return send_from_directory(public, 'index.html')

# start the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Where I just serve a static HTML files from `/public` folder when `/` is requested.

I'm using bower to install bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
```

But the problem is that the files are not being found although the path is correct.

Can someone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Is `bower_components` in public/?

Comment: Yes, it is in /public folder, thats why is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the path for my bower_components should be /public/bower_components/../../

Answer (score 5):

It took me ages to figure this out. You have to import `send_from_directory` explicitly and also use `__name__`

```
from eve import Eve
from flask import send_from_directory

app = Eve(__name__, static_folder="static")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return send_from_directory("static", 'index.html')

app.run()
```

Then in `settings.py`:

```
URL_PREFIX="api"
```

Static file delivery:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/images/image.jpg
http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/style.css
```

API calls:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/person/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in another thread a question regarding templates and it works quite well for static files, too:

```
template_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
static_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
app = Eve(settings=settings, static_url_path='/static', template_folder=template_folder, static_folder=static_folder)
```

Comment: Please show us your source (the other thread), maybe there is other useful stuff in there. If it answers the question you can also flag this question as duplicate and linking to your source.